# Execute Function On First Run Of Greasemonkey Script

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

How can I run a function upon the first run of a greasemonkey script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GM_setValue` and `GM_getValue` to store setting etc.

Try "getting" a flag. If it isn't set, make your first run call and then set the value. eg

```
var isfirstrun = GM_getValue('firstrun', '0');
if (isfirstrun == '0')
{
    // value not set, so must be the first run
    DoSomething();
    GM_setValue('firstrun', '1');
}
```

The docs are [here](http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/api/gm_setvalue.html)